# Taking over React site. Is there a precompiler?

Tags: reactjs

I have been tasked to maintain an existing React site.  It appears that all .js and .jsx files are being compiled into one react-application.js file. I have made some changes to the code and need to move the code to staging. However I am not sure how to proceed. Being fairly new to React I am sure I have missed something here. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Image of the root folder as requested:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcIh2.png

Image of the resources/assets/js folder:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaHew.png

Comment: That "one" file depends on the naming convention that was given to it in the webpack.config.js file when it was compiled my assumption was it was perhaps called bundle.js. If so, to compile it once again, you need to run `npm run` whatever the build script for production was called in the package.json file.

Comment: A list of the files in the root of the project might be helpful to figure this out. There are a number of possible tools that could have been used to bundle your javascript: webpack, rollup, babel, gulp, etc . . .  A list of the files in the project root (looking for a config file) and/or the contents of `package.json` might give us some clue.

Comment: Updated with the requested images.  Thank you!

Comment: @dave Dave I attached the screenshots is there anything else I can attach to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there's two important files I see in the root directory:

1. package.json
2. gulpfile.js

#### package.json

If you're not familiar with [npm](https://www.npmjs.com), you're going to need to be. `package.json` lists all the npm packages that are required to build and run this project. Once you have npm installed globally, you're going to want to run `npm install` on the command line from the root of your project.

#### gulpfile.js

`gulpfile.js` is a script that should be executed by the task runner [gulp](https://gulpjs.com). You're also going to want to have gulp installed and review the documentation to familiarize yourself with it. Your `gulpfile.js` will define one or more tasks. One of these most will likely transpile and bundle your `.jsx` files into a single browser friendly script. It most likely makes use of other npm packages to do so, which you also may need to familiarize yourself with.

You can run these various tasks by calling `gulp [taskname]` from the command line in the root directory. Quite likely there is a master task set to default which will run by simply calling `gulp`.

There's a pretty good chance gulp is also set to compile Sass and handle other tasks as well.

---

One more thing. The root directory also contains a `.bowerrc`. This would have been created by [Bower](https://bower.io), a package manager that was popular before npm. However there is no `bower.json` file, which I would expect to find.

This is a bit of a red flag for me. Hopefully, all of your dependencies are now included via `package.json` and whoever removed Bower just neglected to clean up the `.bowerrc`. But if your build process still depends on Bower assets, not having a `bower.json` is going to be a problem.

Comment: I was able to use npm to install the needed packages and gulp to compile the js file!  Thank you for your help!